# Dragging to Highlight Text in Magnific Popup Closes Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

I'm trying to fix an issue with the login popup/box on my WordPress using the Kallyas theme. This login box is a Magnific Popup with some text s on it. When you drag to select the text in an  and release the mouse outside of the popup, the popup closes.

I've scoured the Magnific Popup and Kallyas docs, as well as the Kallyas source code. None of those gave me any meaningful insights. I've also tested my issue with a simple, blank, standalone HTML document that has a single Magnific Popup on it. Highlighting any text in the popup and releasing off of it still closed it, so I'm convinced it's not caused by my site's particular configuration/code.

How do I prevent a Magnific Popup from closing if the mouse was only released outside of the popup, and not fully clicked?